# Building Xalanc 1.12 on Redhat 8 - Trouble with Cmake errors

Tags: c++, cmake, icu, xerces, xalan

I'm trying to build Xalan 1.12, using the ICU transcoder, on Redhat 8. I've already built ICU 70.1 and Xerces 3.2.3.

I can build Xalan without any problems so long as I use the default transcoder. When I try to use the ICU transcoder I get a list of errors very similar to these.

[image]

Here are the setting I'm using for the CMake generation

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ICU_ROOT/lib:$XercesC_ROOT/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

ICU_ARGS="-DICU_LIBRARY=$ICU_ROOT/lib/libicuio.so.70.1 -DICU_INCLUDE_DIR=$ICU_ROOT/include/"

XERCES_ARGS="-DXercesC_LIBRARY=$XercesC_ROOT/lib/libxerces-c-3.2.so -DXercesC_INCLUDE_DIR=$XercesC_ROOT/include/ -DXercesC_VERSION=$XercesC_VERSION"

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -Dtranscoder=icu -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$XALAN_HOME/1.12-install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release $XERCES_ARGS $ICU_ARGS ../1.12

cmake --build . --config=Release
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Documentation for module [FindICU.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindICU.html) doesn't list CMake variable `ICU_LIBRARY` as a possible hint for search ICU library. It smells like your setting of that variable confuses the module to report that ICU has been found while it is actually not found. According to the same documentation, setting `ICU_ROOT` environment variable should be sufficient for the hint. If that hint doesn't work, then something wrong with your ICU installation. E.g. that installation should contain pure `.so` files, not only ones with soversion (`.so.70.1`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the input! I was able to fix the error by creating a new install directory that only contained the `.so` files, as you suggested.

I also went back and removed my definition of `ICU_LIBRARY` and added definitions for `ICU_ROOT`, `ICU_INCLUDE_DIR`, and `ICU_LIBARIES`. 

Thanks again!